# How to pass parameters from angular 4 to access REST API data

Tags: angular, authentication

I have created the service to access the REST API data but when i hit the url from the Angular application end then it gives me this error in the console.

```
Failed to load http://<SERVER.URL.FROM.SERVER>/api/invoice-details/121: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

So for that the backend guy gave some authentication parameters like

[image]

So he is telling me to pass the parameters For Authentication to access the data in my Angular application. Otherwise i can get the same error like CORS.

So my question is how to pass the parameters from my end. I have written the code like this in the user.service.ts where all my services are there.

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'UTF-8' });
    private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });

    constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig) {}

getSupplierBasicInfo(){
        return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + 'api/supplier-basic-info/121')
        .map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

In the component i am calling the service like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-invoice',
  templateUrl: './invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invoice.component.css']
})
export class InvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  invoiceDetails: any[];
  constructor(private _userService: UserService) { 
    console.log('Invoice Details loaded!');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getInvoiceDetails()
    .subscribe(data => this.invoiceDetails = data);
  }
}
```

Data binding is like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr style="background-color:#55555A; color:#ffffff">
        <th scope="col">Req ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Details</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">View</th>
        <th scope="col">Download</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of orderDetails">
            <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.field_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.field_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.field_first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.field_upload_invoice }}</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

So can anybody help me that how to pass the parameters to get the data in my application.

Answer (score 0):

**Imports:**

```
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

**Headers:**

```
    private headers = new Headers([
            { 'credentials': 'same-origin' },
            { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            //instead of * you can specify your host 
            { 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' },
        ]);
        //private params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(); 
        private options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers,
withCredentials: true 
});
```

**Request:**

```
this.options.search = this.params;
this.http.get(`${this.host}${this.url}`, this.options)
            .map(result => result.json());
```

You can also specyfi CORS on web api configuration file to add headers to every request.

Comment: Even after adding this code also i am still getting the same issue what i have experienced before like Failed to load http://URL/api/contact-details/54: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://URL:8080' is therefore not allowed access.   ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: Looks like your server does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response to a preflight request (OPTIONS). A CORS request will fail if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing.

Comment: How to use the basic authorization in the headers like the passing username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below thing in web.config file

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This will definitely help you.